# Elastic tokenize into all possible word cominations

Tags: elasticsearch, combinations, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-2.0

Given input "*quick brown fox jumped*" I would like to create every possible token combination for words. So the example string would be tokenized to

```
[
"quick", "quick brown", "quick fox", "quick jumped",
"brown", "brown quick", "brown fox", "brown jumped",
                      ...,
"jumped quick", "jumped brown", "jumped fox", "jumped"
]
```

I could use [shingle tokeniser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) for it but it only creates new tokens by concatenating adjacent terms and I end up with:

```
[
"quick", "quick brown", "quick brown fox", "quick brown fox jumped",
"brown", "brown fox", "brown fox jumped",
"fox", "fox jumped",
"jumped"
]
```

Which is the right step forward but not the thing Im looking for.

Comment: Can you explain the use case you're after?

Comment: @Val Long story short - to produce term aggregations not only on single terms (["quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped"]) but also on combinations of these words/terms

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you said the use case here is to get aggregations of combinations of words that appear in the document. You can use the standard tokenizer, and still get that information. For example, suppose you have the documents with the "body" field:

> 1: The quick brown fox jumps over the little dog
>
> 2: The little dog eats some food

So I think you want to see something like:

> little dog: 2
>
> the little: 2
>
> the dog: 2
>
> the eats: 1
>
> ...

Then you can query like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "firstlevel": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "body"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "secondlevel": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "body"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and you get a response like:

```
"aggregations": {
  "firstlevel": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 1,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "dog",
      "doc_count": 2,
      "secondlevel": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 1,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "dog",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "little",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "the",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "brown",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
       ...
```

And you can see that "little" and "dog" co-occur in 2 docs, and "the" and "dog" co-occur in 2 documents, and "dog" and "brown" co-occur in 1 document. Of course this only works if you want **unique** co-occurence count.

In case you really need to have the tokens like you've describe, I think you have to write code to do that (either a custom tokenizer for Lucene which you can use from Elasticsearch, or probably easier, a pre-processing step which adds a field that's a list of `keyword`s).